# alinhar conteúdo de uma <div> no centro da tela

Tags: asp.net

Tenho um loading e ele está em uma `<div>`. Acontece que ele dispara sempre à esquerda e gostaria que ele ficasse no centro da página, mas como está em uma `<div>`, achei que poderia ser isso.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <div id="loading" style="align-content:center">        
        Carregando....
        <div><img src="../Imagens/wait2.gif" /></div>        
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto é `text-align:center`

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <div id="loading" style="text-align:center">        
        Carregando....
        <div><img src="../Imagens/wait2.gif" /></div>        
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Vou marcar sua resposta, mas eu fiz assim e não funfou, mas rodei fora do ambiente de localhost e funcionou, mas se eu rodo em localhost(desenvolvimento) não vai nem a pau.

Comment: Ainda não deu certo? Vê se esse id loading tem algum text-align:left !important;. A única forma de um CSS inline não funcionar é se tiver algum outro elemento dando !important na mesma propriedade.